# Plus-que-parfait, passé antérieur et passé simple dans une phrase

Tags: plus-que-parfait

J'ai rencontré un passage de texte intéressant, où trois temps passés apparaissaient dans la même phrase :

> Rapidement, il parcourut la cave, le grenier. Il ne s’arrêtait pour
> ainsi dire point, sachant bien qu’il ne découvrirait pas en quelques
> minutes ce que ses hommes n’avaient pu découvrir en trois heures. Mais
> il enregistrait fidèlement la forme et l’enchaînement des pièces.
>
> **Quand il eut fini, il revint vers une chambre que Doudeville
> lui avait
> indiquée comme celle d'Altenheim, et l'examina attentivement.**
>
> *[Maurice Leblanc, "813"](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/813/06)*

Comme vous pouvez le constater, l'auteur utilise le passé antérieur (*eut fini*), puis le passé simple (*revint*), le plus-que-parfait (*avait indiqué*) et enfin le passé simple une fois de plus (*examina*).

Les actions décrites par les verbes "revint" et "examina" se sont déroulées à peu près en même temps, elles ont donc toutes deux été mises au passé simple.
Concernant les deux autres verbes, ils font référence aux actions qui se sont produites plus tôt, c'est, si je comprends bien, la fonction des deux temps passé anterieur et plus-que-parfait.

Y a-t-il une raison pratique pour laquelle l’auteur ne les a pas mis au même temps (*eut fini* et *avait indiquée*)?

Comment: Impossible à mon avis. Peux-tu proposer ce que tu aurais mis? J'ai essayé et rien ne semble marcher.

Comment: @Frank C'est évident pour toi parce que tu es francophone et tu n'as pas besoin d'y réfléchir, c'est spontané, mais pour un non francophone cette concordance des temps est très difficile à comprendre. C'est le genre d'erreurs/d'hésitation qui persistent longtemps même chez ceux qui ont un niveau avancé, encore plus si leur langue maternelle a un système de temps moins complexe que celui du français.

Comment: @Frank Comme ça, par example: Quand il eut fini, il revint vers une chambre que Doudeville lui eut indiquée comme celle d'Altenheim, et l'examina attentivement. ou: Quand il avait fini, il revint vers une chambre que Doudeville lui avait indiquée comme celle d'Altenheim, et l'examina attentivement.

Comment: @int21h Ça ne marche pas. _Que Doudeville lui avait indiquée_ est la seule solution ici. None a une très bonne explication dans sa réponse. _Avait indiquée_ est le temps requis ici pour démarquer ce verbe de _revint_ et indiquer une action _antérieure_ à celle de _revint_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le passé antérieur (*eut fini*) exprime l'antériorité **immédiate** introduite par une conjonction de temps (*quand*) par rapport à l'action au passé simple (*il revint et examina*).

Le plus-que-parfait (*avait indiquée*) exprime une antériorité qui **n'est pas forcément immédiate** par rapport à l'action au passé simple (*revint et examina*). Par rapport à l'action au passé simple l'action au plus-que-parfait est plus éloignée dans le temps que l'action au passé antérieur.

Si dans la même phrase les deux actions décrites par les verbes *finir* et *indiquer* avaient été mises au même temps, ça aurait signifié qu'elles se passaient en même temps, ce qui n'est pas le cas.

*Le bon usage** :

> Le plus-que-parfait indique, comme le passé antérieur, un fait qui a eu lieu avant un autre fait passé, mais il s'emploie pour marquer une antériorité indéterminée.

---

*<sub>§727, 10<sup>e</sup> édition</sub>